# monitor bandwidth on multiple subdomains that share the same ip (Windows/IIS)

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, web-hosting, subdomain, bandwidth

I have seen the following:
[Tool to track bandwidth by domain name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/223106/tool-to-track-bandwidth-by-domain-name)
and
[How can I monitor bandwidth usage by Virtual Host in Apache on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/119286/how-can-i-monitor-bandwidth-usage-by-virtual-host-in-apache-on-ubuntu)

We use IIS7 on a Windows Server 2008. We have our Domain and then about 5 subdomains being served from the same IP. I would like to be able to charge our clients for their increased bandwidth.

We also have a Cisco ASA 5505 if it is possible to use that appliance to monitor the bandwidth for requests.

If this is not possible that is acceptable and we will get more IPs but would like confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way round this is using the Bytes count of Web Analyser software like Web Trends. There should be lots of free ones.

--edit-

Sorry if that wasn't entirely clear. The analyser software will count each site's bandwidth count and usually mention it at the foot of the reports it produces. That way each Virtual Server, ie site or subdomain, on the Web Server gets a request count in MB or Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Your web log will provide counts of bytes sent for every request.  You may need to configure it to log the domain as well has the bytes send.   The domain may not be in your default log format.  Any number of log analysis tools will summarize the data.

This will not capture the request size, but that tends to be a relatively small volume for most web applications.